# Is There an HBase 1.2 Equivalent of Accumulo's RegExFilter?

Tags: regex, hbase, accumulo

I have a background in [Accumulo 1.6](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/), and I've been directed to analyze the [API of HBase 1.2](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/). Does HBase 1.2 have a built-in functional equivalent to the RegExFilter in Accumulo? I've not seen one, so below I've attempted to hack up something that's functionally equivalent.

On the Accumulo side...

Accumulo's RegExFilter supports regular expressions in any combination of these fields:

- Row
- Column Family
- Column Qualifier
- Value

RegExFilter has an option to support "OR" behavior across the expressions -- to return the entry if any of the expressions match.

RegExFilter has an option to support matches on substrings.

On the HBase 1.2 side, my understanding is that...

- A RegexStringComparator can be used to filter a field by using it with a CompareFilter implementation.
- A RowFilter can filter based on the row key portion of the key
- A QualifierFilter can filter based on the column qualifier portion of the key
- A ValueFilter can filter based on the value
- Multiple filters can be added to a FilterList, itself a subclass of Filter, and AND/OR behavior can be defined among the Filters in the FilterList.

In HBase, to mimic Accumulo's RegExFilter, I could do something like the following:

```
List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();

// Regex for row
if (rowRegEx != null) {
   filters.add(new RowFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,
         new RegexStringComparator(rowRegEx));
}

// Regex for column family
if (colFamRegEx != null) {
   filters.add(new FamilyFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,
         new RegexStringComparator(colFamRegEx));
}

// Regex for column qualifier
if (colQualRegEx != null) {
   filters.add(new QualifierFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,
         new RegexStringComparator(colQualRegEx));
}

// Regex for value
if (valRegEx != null) {
   filters.add(new ValueFilter(CompareOp.EQUAL,
         new RegexStringComparator(valRegEx));
}

// For "or" behavior, use FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE
FilterList filterList = new FilterList(
      FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL, filters);
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(filterList);

// TODO How to mimic "match on substring" behavior of RegExFilter?
```

**Question 1** Does my (untested) code snippet seem like a legitimate HBase 1.2 equivalent to Accumulo 1.6's RegExFilter? If not, then what could be improved?

**Question 2** I assume Accumulo's RegExFilter's "match on substrings" option could be implemented in HBase 1.2 using a slightly differently defined regular expression. Is there a less clunky way to do this, so that ideally I could use the same regular expression in both Accumulo and HBase?